# Sharepoint Upload Multiple Document Option Gray Out

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-office

To enable Sharepoint 2010 Upload Multiple Document option STSUpld UploadCtl must be enabled in add on. Some clients are getting multiple upload option grayed out.

So I checked systems of client which have issue. On some of systems there was STSUPLD.DLL present but **STSUpld UploadCtl** Class was not listed under Add-on in internet explorer. Is any thing more needed after the  installation of office to install this Add on.

Please suggest....

Comment: Which version of Office do the users have?  Have you seen this setting that needs to be set in Central Admin? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691367

Comment: Office 2013 and version is 15.0.4420.1017. Yes I checked the central admin setting which is related to multiple upload these are fine..

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the DLL File is in the appropriate location, and then see if the Active X add on is then available in IE 11

1. DLL Location:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\STSUPLD.DLL – For Office 2013
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\STSUPLD.DLL  – For Office 2010.
2. Active X:
   There is an ActiveX Control named as STSUpld.UploadCtl  in the Manage Add-ons option that must be enabled in IE.